# Есть профиль пользователя, как реализовать загрузку аватарки для пользователя?

Tags: php, html, база-данных, phpmyadmin, redbeanphp

Ох, в общем, я не сильно знаком с php и базами данных, но надо сделать курсач, у меня есть регистрация пользователей на сайте, и есть профиль пользователя, так вот мне нужно, чтоб пользователь загружал картинку и она отображалась в виде аватарки у него в профиле. У меня есть готовый кусок кода, который закидывает картинку, который загрузил пользователь в папку uploads/avatars, этот код так же преобразует название файла.

```
{
    // если имя пустое, значит файл не выбран
    if ($file['name'] == '')
        return 'Вы не выбрали файл.';

    /* если размер файла 0, значит его не пропустили настройки
    сервера из-за того, что он слишком большой */
    if ($file['size'] == 0)
        return 'Файл слишком большой.';

    // разбиваем имя файла по точке и получаем массив
    $getMime = explode('.', $file['name']);
    // нас интересует последний элемент массива - расширение
    $mime = strtolower(end($getMime));
    // объявим массив допустимых расширений
    $types = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'jpeg');

    // если расширение не входит в список допустимых - return
    if (!in_array($mime, $types))
        return 'Недопустимый тип файла.';

    return true;
}

function make_upload($file)
{
    // формируем уникальное имя картинки: случайное число и name
    $name = mt_rand(0, 10000) . $file['name'];
    copy($file['tmp_name'], 'uploads/avatars/' . $name);
```

сама форма отправки:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Загрузить файл!">
    </form>
    <?php
    // если была произведена отправка формы
    if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        // проверяем, можно ли загружать изображение
        $check = can_upload($_FILES['file']);

        if($check === true){
            // загружаем изображение на сервер
            make_upload($_FILES['file']);
            echo "<strong>Файл успешно загружен!</strong>";
        }
        else{
            // выводим сообщение об ошибке
            echo "<strong>$check</strong>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

**Мне нужно чтоб название этой картинки отправлялась в базу данных:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я делал регистрацию/войти и саму базу данных с помощью RedBeanPHP по тутору
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за помощь, я правда пытался сам сделать, но чёт вообще никак :(

Answer (score 0):

Из того, что я понял функция `make_upload` должна имя возвращать, следовательно нужно прям этот метод вызывать в $user->avatar = `{вызов метода}`